Undo Restoration of emails from "Recoverable Items" folder, performed via OWA/Outlook Web
Unbeknownst to me, recovering emails from "Recoverable Items" behaves differently in OWA than in Desktop:
https://aacc.teamdynamix.com/TDClient/2439/Portal/KB/ArticleDet?ID=147693#:~:text=30%20days%20after%20deletion%2C%20items,item%20(Shift%20%2B%20Delete)
I've only known the Desktop version, which restores Recoverable emails to your "Deleted Items" folder.
However, if you perform the same action in OWA, it restores the emails to their original location (usually the Inbox, or a folder within the Inbox).
I restored 700+ emails via OWA on a Shared Inbox. I immediately pressed "Cancel" about a second after I made the mistake, but it did nothing. Due to Microsoft's 2015 removal of the default 30-day retention policy in the Deleted Items folder (replacing it with an "indefinite" retention policy)...:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2015/02/20/extended-email-retention-deleted-items-office-365/
https://www.michev.info/blog/post/5868/make-sure-deleted-items-are-automatically-removed-from-microsoft-365-mailboxes/comment-page-1#comment-13028
...this action has restored ancient emails into the Inbox subfolders that were deleted/cleaned up long ago.
In hopes of undoing each of these email Restorations one-by-one, I ran a PowerShell command to gather all Operations performed on the Shared Mailbox within the past 3 days. (I did the Restoration 1.5 days ago, MST time.):
# Force TLS 1.2 to avoid related error
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

# Connect to Exchange
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName "SharedMailbox@contoso.com"

Search-MailboxAuditLog -Identity "SharedMailbox@contoso.com”  -LogonTypes Admin,Delegate,Owner -StartDate 10/21/2024 -EndDate 10/24/2024 -ShowDetails | 
    select-object Operation, OperationResult, LogonType, logonuserdisplayname, SourceItemSubjectsList, itemsubject, SourceItemFolderPathNamesList, LastAccessed, InternalLogonType, MailboxOwnerUPN, ClientIPAddress,ClientProcessName,ClientInfoString, ClientVersion | 
    export-csv "C:\users\me\Desktop\out5.csv" -NoTypeInformation 

However, from my research, restoring emails to Inbox would fall under the "Move" Operation. Unfortunately, the default Auditing setting for "Delegates" of a Shared Inbox (at least mine) is to NOT log any "Move" Operations. (The restoration was performed using a "Delegate" account of the Shared Mailbox.):
PS C:\Users\me> Get-Mailbox SharedMailbox@contoso.com | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AuditDelegate
Update
MoveToDeletedItems
SoftDelete
HardDelete
SendAs
SendOnBehalf
Create
UpdateFolderPermissions
UpdateInboxRules
ApplyRecord
MailItemsAccessed

So, I then ran a PowerShell command to gather all SoftDelete/HardDelete/MoveToDeletedItems Operations starting from Jan 1 2022, in hopes to replicate all deletions performed over the past few years, one-by-one:
# Force TLS 1.2 to avoid related error
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

# Connect to Exchange
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName "SharedMailbox@contoso.com"

Search-MailboxAuditLog -Identity "SharedMailbox@contoso.com" -LogonTypes Admin,Delegate,Owner -StartDate "01/01/2022" -EndDate "10/24/2024" -ShowDetails | 
    Where-Object { ($_.Operation -eq "HardDelete" -or $_.Operation -eq "SoftDelete" -or $_.Operation -eq "MoveToDeletedItems") } | 
    Select-Object Operation, OperationResult, LogonType, LogonUserDisplayName, SourceItemSubjectsList, ItemSubject, SourceItemFolderPathNamesList, Received, LastAccessed, InternalLogonType, MailboxOwnerUPN, ClientIPAddress, ClientProcessName, ClientInfoString, ClientVersion | 
    Export-Csv "C:\users\me\Desktop\out.csv" -NoTypeInformation

However, since the default Auditing log policy is to only go back 90 days--while, again, the default Deleted Items retention policy is "Indefinite" (very convenient)--This only showed deletion Operations performed over the past 90 days. I'd need to see all deletions performed over the past few years (or since the Mailbox's origin), to replicate the deletions in a way that ensures all emails are deleted from the Inbox subfolders that were deleted originally. (Again, ideally I'd be able to view all the "Move" Operations/email restorations that I performed...but as I said, the "Move" operation wasn't being logged for the Shared Mailbox's delegates. [Though it is now...])
I emailed Microsoft support.
I know this is pretty dire, but are there any ideas out there to undo the bulk email Recovery from Recoverable Items? Thank you in advance.
